# Comma after a conditional clause in the middle of a sentence

Tags: american-english, conditional-constructions, relative-clauses, commas, subordinate-clauses

The description of some algorithm (searching in a program-transition graph for a program state with certain properties) finishes with

> We return “true” if we find such a state(,) and “false” otherwise.

The parens around the comma mean that it's unclear whether the comma belongs there or not.  Is the comma before “and”

1. necessary,
2. forbidden,
3. optional with a change in the meaning, or
4. optional without a change in the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for it, so I would recommend omitting it.

I can think of two reasons that might justify a comma there:

1: A comma with a FANBOYS conjunction can separate two main clauses. However, in order for there to be a main clause after "and", we would have to assume that some words were omitted:

> We return “true” if we find such a state, and [[we return]] “false” otherwise.

It is somewhat unusual to omit both a subject and its verb, so I don't like this option.

2: Paired commas can surround a nonrestrictive element. However, I think that "“false” otherwise" works better if it is restrictive, because it seems to be an important part of the sentence.

If we omit the comma, then "and" simply connects two items in series: "“true” if we find such a state" and "“false” otherwise". That is perfectly grammatical and easily understandable, and it involves one less piece of punctuation. To answer your actual question, I would say that the comma is optional without a change in meaning but that the sentence is better without it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if it separates two separate clauses - https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html

In your case it wouldn't change the meaning, but "reads" better. It suggests a short pause when speaking

Comment: Thx! So, do we have two clauses or don't we? Or is there a choice here?